# Disable payment method only for admin?

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I design one payment gateway But It's hosted payment so i want remove that payment method for admin order and reorder.so please some one tell me how to disable this method only for admin orders like Paypal standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jaydeep Sinh Parmar,can do this by [Magento Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

First,using **payment_method_is_active** disable on depends current store.

Code for this:

Module config.xml code:

```
<global>
    <events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
            <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
            <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
            </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</global>
```

### Observer code is:

```
<?php
class YOURNANESPACE_YOURMODULE_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    /* call get payment method */
    $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();

     /*   get  Quote  */
     $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    /* Disable Your payment method for   adminStore */
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()):
        if($method->getCode()=='YOUR_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE' ){
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
         $result->isAvailable = false;
        }
    endif;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me which event observer?

Comment: So amit what i have to write in observer.

Comment: Are you want full module.I have disabled your method for only for admin

Comment: I already module it's works good.i am apply your solution if it's work then nothing i needed more.

Comment: Amit can you tell me how can i know my payment method code?

Comment: you need goto your payment  module code  and go it Model class here find $_code  variable ,it value,your payment method.see Default magento CashOndelivery code at clas Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery  .protected $_code  = 'cashondelivery';

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Please check the last Answer for this following stackOverflow Link:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011348/disable-payment-options-only-cash-on-delivery-for-particular-product-magento

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this extension. It allows you to set payment methods to only be used in the backend http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-payments.html

The code is available on github (https://github.com/getsquare/Magento-Admin-Payments)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System > Configuration` and select the `Default Config` as the `current configuration scope.`
Then select Payment methods tab and `disable` your payment method.

OR

you can simply disable it in your module's system.xml where the configurations are located

That will done the job for you

Comment: But this way payment method disable for fronted also.

Comment: It shouldn't. Make sure you have selected the correct option as the current configuration drop down

Comment: I think you tell me to disable                              system->configuration->Sale->payment-method->My-Method         Enable = No.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But ensure what is the configuration scope you selected.

Comment: yes if i follow this process with right scope it will surely remove that payment method for back-end as well as front-end at checkout & I don't want to remove that payment method for customer checkout.By the way i find right answer   and again thanks for your time.

Comment: @Sukeshini can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302345/57334 thanks

Comment: @zus I added a solution to the link you provided.